# issue on Glade Gui

Tags: c++, glade

I'm trying to work on glade Gui and I have used some Gui buttons like `button1` and `button2`. Actually, my basic task is to capture the live video. For this, I used this command when i press gui button1 this command should work-> `system("avconv -f video4linux2 -r 10 -s 1280x768 -i /dev/video0 -y record.avi");` and this is in looping (continuously running) in command line. In the running task one option is there to stop the recording. For example, `to stop recording press q`. if I press `q` from the keyboard it is working fine, through program if I press gui `button2` with `system("q");` it is not working its showing like

> sh:1 q: not found

I am not able to stop the running task(video recording) through the program. pls, do help me how can I do this task. I am struggling from past 2to3 days.
I am using the thread concept.

your help will be highly appreciated!
thank u
Ramesh

this is how running in command line continuosly:

> Stream mapping: Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> mpeg4 (native))
>   Press [q] to stop, [?] for help frame=   63 fps= 10 q=3.3 Lsize=
>   237kB time=00:00:06.30 bitrate= 308.8kbits/s speed=1.01x

Comment: system("q") is creating an independent execution environment ("shell"), and not sending anything to the previous command. Hence the "q: not found", as there are no program called q...

Comment: tq u for your valuable resp, is there any way to stop recording through the program

Comment: find and kill the process? Or see these links that say to not use system() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-do-i-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c-using-posix and https://www.quora.com/Can-a-C-C++-program-fork-a-bash-shell-and-pass-commands-to-execute-If-yes-which-library-functions-do-you-use